# Find / Replace Multiple Substrings from Table in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm copy/pasting text into a cell in Excel which has specific substrings that need replacing, from a list of ~4,000 rows. I have an equal number of pieces of text/content as the number of rows, which I'll need to manually copy/paste in.

Essentially, specific substrings need to be replaced with the same substring, wrapped with a HTML link, but this needs to happen for all occurrences of any substring from my list.

## Example:

### I have this text:

`Microsoft Excel is a spreadsheet developed by Microsoft for Windows, Mac OS X, and iOS.`

### In sheet #2, I have the following;

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paz6Y.png)

### I then need excel to output the text above, with the strings specified replaced with links in the following format:

`<a href="http://www.apple.com/uk/mac/">Mac</a>`

### In this example, it would output the following:

`<a href="https://www.microsoft.com/">Microsoft</a> Excel is a spreadsheet developed by <a href="https://www.microsoft.com/">Microsoft</a> for <a href="https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows">Windows
</a>, <a href="http://www.apple.com/uk/mac/">Mac</a> OS X, and iOS.`

I'm no excel expert, so I've not been able to find a solution. One answer on SO suggested the following to a different question;
`=SUBSTITUTE(A2,"Author","Authoring")`
But I'm not sure how I could edit this to include all of the strings without needing to manually add every single one to the formula, as this will currently just replace each string one by one.

Has anyone done anything similar to this before? If so, how did you do it?

Comment: If there are just three strings in the list it would be feasible to do it by substitution, either using a nested formula or three successive formulae. If you have many more, it wouldn't and you might be looking at a VBA solution.

Comment: @TomSharpe Thanks, unfortunately theres one piece of content for each of ~4,000 strings, so VBA will probably be where I need to look next. Though, it's not something I've ever used....

Comment: On sheet2 is it always Mac, Windows and Microsoft?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest problem you face in a situation like this is false positives. When one word or phrase can be found within another word or phrase, you may end up 'double-processing' or wrongly processing a search term. To avoid this, process each term in a descending order of length and do it in two steps. First, replace the search term with an absolutely unique temporary string and once all of the terms have been reassigned, go back and replace the temporary strings with the actual HTML anchor elements.

**Module1 code sheet**

```
Option Explicit

Public Const csANCHOR As String = "<a href=""×LL×"">×FN×</a>"

Sub processBlurbs()
    Dim m As Long, w As Long
    Dim vWRDs As Variant, vBLRBs As Variant, vMSKs As Variant
    Dim rw As Long, r As Long, rndm As Long, str As String

    'appTGGL bTGGL:=False  'uncomment after testing

    getReplacements vWRDs
    'Debug.Print LBound(vWRDs, 1) & ":" & UBound(vWRDs, 1)
    'Debug.Print LBound(vWRDs, 2) & ":" & UBound(vWRDs, 2)

    With Worksheets("Blurbs")
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion

            'replace with associated GUID for unique-per-term
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 1)
                'reset column B to column A values
                .Cells = .Offset(0, -1).Value2
                For w = LBound(vWRDs, 1) To UBound(vWRDs, 1)
                    Debug.Print vWRDs(w, 1) & " - " & vWRDs(w, 4)
                    .Replace what:=vWRDs(w, 1), lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=True, _
                             replacement:=vWRDs(w, 4)
                Next w
            End With

            'replace GUIDs with associated ANCHOR elements
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 1)
                For w = LBound(vWRDs, 1) To UBound(vWRDs, 1)
                    .Replace what:=vWRDs(w, 4), lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=True, _
                             replacement:=Replace(Replace(csANCHOR, "×LL×", vWRDs(w, 2)), "×FN×", vWRDs(w, 1))
                Next w
            End With

        End With
    End With

    appTGGL
End Sub

Sub getReplacements(ByRef wrds As Variant)
    With Worksheets("Replacements")
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 2)
                .FormulaR1C1 = "=LEN(RC1)"
                .Value = .Value2
            End With
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 3)
                .Formula = "=getGuid()"
                .Value = .Value2
            End With
            .Cells.Sort key1:=.Columns(3), order1:=xlDescending, _
                        key2:=.Columns(1), order2:=xlAscending, _
                        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
                wrds = .Cells.Value2
            End With
        End With
    End With
End Sub

Function getGuid() As String
    Dim tl As Object
    Set tl = CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib")
    getGuid = tl.Guid
    Set tl = Nothing
End Function

Sub appTGGL(Optional bTGGL As Boolean = True)
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = bTGGL
        .ScreenUpdating = bTGGL
        .DisplayAlerts = bTGGL
        .Calculation = IIf(bTGGL, xlCalculationAutomatic, xlCalculationManual)
    End With
End Sub
```

Step through this with repeated taps to the [F8] key to get an idea of the logic and process  flow.

**Replacements worksheet**

[image: replacement_values]

**Blurbs worksheet**

[image: blurbs_worksheet]

---

**Results**

```html
Lorem <a href="http://www.apple.com/uk/osx">Mac OS X</a> dolor sit amet, consectetur <a href="http://www.ibm.com/">IBM</a> elit.
<br/>
Quisque <a href="http://www.ibm.com/">IBM</a> dolor <a href="http://www.apple.com/uk/mac">Mac</a> ante vestibulum, eget <a href="https://www.microsoft.com/">Microsoft</a> sapien tempus.
<br/>
Duis tristique sapien non <a href="https://www.microsoft.com/">Microsoft</a> <a href="https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows">Microsoft Windows</a> porta.
<br/>
Praesent <a href="http://www.apple.com/uk/ios">Mac iOS</a> urna id metus fringilla, non mattis sem porttitor.
<br/>
Nunc bibendum <a href="http://www.ibm.com/">IBM</a> <a href="https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows">Microsoft Windows</a> ligula varius vestibulum.
<br/>
Nulla sollicitudin elit nec mauris <a href="http://www.ibm.com/">IBM</a> <a href="https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows">Microsoft Windows</a>
<br/>
Duis <a href="http://www.ibm.com/">IBM</a> <a href="http://www.apple.com/uk/osx">Mac OS X</a> id <a href="https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows">Microsoft Windows</a> volutpat.
<br/>
Nullam <a href="http://www.apple.com/uk/ios">Mac iOS</a> dolor sed <a href="https://www.microsoft.com/">Microsoft</a> consequat <a href="https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows">Windows</a> quis eu purus.
<br/>
Nullam <a href="https://www.microsoft.com/">Microsoft</a> dolor eget <a href="https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows">Microsoft Windows</a> <a href="http://www.apple.com/uk/osx">Mac OS X</a> <a href="http://www.apple.com/uk/ios">Mac iOS</a>
<br/>
Vivamus <a href="http://www.apple.com/uk/mac">Mac</a> leo non <a href="https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows">Windows</a> pharetra pretium a malesuada dolor.
<br/>
Donec condimentum leo <a href="https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows">Windows</a> dictum <a href="http://www.ibm.com/">IBM</a>
<br/>
Nullam aliquam velit <a href="https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows">Windows</a> ullamcorper <a href="https://www.microsoft.com/">Microsoft</a>
<br/>
Curabitur <a href="https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows">Windows</a> leo eget magna eleifend, <a href="http://www.apple.com/uk/osx">Mac OS X</a> posuere velit tincidunt.
<br/>
Aenean pulvinar quam <a href="http://www.apple.com/uk/mac">Mac</a> <a href="http://www.apple.com/uk/ios">Mac iOS</a> <a href="https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows">Microsoft Windows</a>
<br/>
Aliquam <a href="https://www.microsoft.com/">Microsoft</a> diam non ipsum egestas <a href="https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows">Microsoft Windows</a>
<br/>
Phasellus in lorem <a href="http://www.ibm.com/">IBM</a> <a href="http://www.apple.com/uk/ios">Mac iOS</a> mauris tempus, laoreet nunc.
<br/>
Vestibulum accumsan justo eu <a href="http://www.ibm.com/">IBM</a> tristique, <a href="https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows">Microsoft Windows</a> massa ornare.
<br/>
Proin lobortis quam <a href="https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows">Windows</a> sem imperdiet, nec <a href="http://www.apple.com/uk/ios">Mac iOS</a> enim aliquet.
```

---